# How to compute the inverse of F distribution in Java?

Tags: java, matlab, distribution

Is there an equivalent function in Java for finv in MATLAB? (finv computes the inverse of the F cumulative distribution function.)

Comment: In J2SE, no.  BTW *"

Thx,

Zsuzsanna"*  Don't include noise like sigs. in questions.  They amount to 4 lines of wasted screen height.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `Apache Commons Math 3.2 API` or the `JSci API`??

After googleing for a little while I came across this page:

http://kickjava.com/src/JSci/maths/statistics/FDistribution.java.htm

which may be helpful in your specific case.